# XSLT - write name template and passing xpath as parameter

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <p c="1">para <style c="Bold">content 1</style> </p>
    <p c="1">para <style c="Bold">content 2</style> </p>
    <p c="1">para <style c="Bold">content 2</style> </p>
    <p c="1">para <style c="Bold">content 2</style> </p>
    <p c="1">para <style c="Bold">content 2</style> </p>
    <s></s>
</doc>
```

my objective is write a name template to count number of preceasing-siblings of `<s>` node and display that number instead if `<s>` node. 
I've written following xsl to do this,

```
<xsl:template name="myTemp">
        <xsl:param name="var" as="node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($var/preceding-sibling::p)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="s">
        <xsl:call-template name="myTemp">
            <xsl:with-param name="var" select="s"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
```

but it gives me `'An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of parameter $var'` in saxon.

Can you give a suggestion to resolve this problem.

Note that : there are simpler ways to count presiding-siblings of `<s>` nodes and print. But what I need is write a name template and write a another template and call that name template.

Comment: "*my objective is write a name template to count number of preceasing-siblings of `<s>` node*" Why don't you simply use the `position()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the template matching `s` it is the context node so you want `<xsl:with-param name="var" select="."/>` instead of `<xsl:with-param name="var" select="s"/>`.